# Coin flip program

Tags: java, coin-flipping

I tried making a program that flips a coin(shows image of heads first and later shows image of tails) and I encountered problems trying to have the image of the coin viewed when I ran the problem; only a blank screen would show.  I don't know whether this is from an improper saving method of the jpg images or from an error in the code.  I also came across an error before again coding the program where I had the heads image show and tails image not show.

CoinTest.java runs coin runner and Coin.java is the class for the program.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CoinTest extends JPanel
implements ActionListener
{
  private Coin coin;

  public CoinTest ()
{
Image heads = (new ImageIcon("quarter-coin-head.jpg")).getImage();
Image tails = (new ImageIcon("Indiana-quarter.jpg")).getImage();
coin = new Coin(heads, tails);

Timer clock = new Timer(2000, this);
clock.start();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
super.paintComponent(g);

int x = getWidth() / 2;
int y = getHeight() / 2;
coin.draw(g, x, y);
}

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
    coin.flip();
    repaint();
   }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
JFrame w = new JFrame("Flipping coin");
w.setSize(300, 300);
w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    CoinTest panel = new CoinTest();
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    Container c = w.getContentPane();
    c.add(panel);

    w.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Now the actual Coin class.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Coin
{
private Image heads;
private Image tails;
private int side = 1;

public Coin(Image h, Image t)
{
    heads = h;
    tails = t;
}

//flips the coin
public void flip()
{
    if (side == 1)
        side = 0;
    else
        side = 1;
}

//draws the appropriate side of the coin - centered  in the JFrame
public void draw(Graphics g, int x, int y)
{
    if (side == 1)
    g.drawImage(heads, heads.getWidth(null)/3, heads.getHeight(null)/3, null);
    else 
    g.drawImage(heads, tails.getWidth(null)/3, tails.getHeight(null)/3, null);
}
}
```

Comment: I would guess that your images aren't loading correctly; double check that your paths are correct.  Also, although this probably isn't related to the issue, you have two int parameters in Coin#draw which never get used.

Comment: If I may propose an easier approach: instead of doing the drawing yourself, add each `ImageIcon` to a `JLabel` and add each to a `JPanel` using a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).  Then when you `flip()` the coin, you need only do `cardLayout.show(coinContainer, "heads")`.

Comment: Should I specify the path starting from C:/?  I had the images inside of my source file, and then I moved to inside the Coin project but outside the source file. I'm specifying /Coin/quarter-coin-head.jpg at  the moment.

Comment: Fixed problem,  by extending the file path all the way to C:.  I had duplicates of the images in different so the paths were the same to some extent(/Coin/quarter-coin-head.jpg).  I'm assuming the compiler didn't know which images i was referring to.  Could that have been why I was getting no images when running the program? Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, ensure that both images are in the correct location to load.

Secondly, you have a typo here:

```
if (side == 1)
  g.drawImage(heads, heads.getWidth(null)/3, heads.getHeight(null)/3, null);
else 
  g.drawImage(heads, tails.getWidth(null)/3, tails.getHeight(null)/3, null);
              ^^^^
```

should be tails...

Comment: Ah, thank you that must have been why only heads was displaying when i originally ran the program.  But I shifted the program to a different computer, and now I have a problem displaying the images.

Comment: fixed. explanation of fix above.

Answer (score 0):

The width and height of the applet are coded in the  tag. The code that draws the applet uses the two methods to get these values at run time. So now, different  tags can ask for the same applet to paint different sized rectangles. The source code does not need to be recompiled for different sizes.